# Including an internal module produces "maybe a missing crate `module2`"

Tags: import, module, rust, compiler-errors

I have the following project structure:

```sh
src
├── module1
│   └── mod.rs
├── main.rs
└── module2
    └── mod.rs
```

but I get a

```rust
error[E0432]: unresolved import `crate::module2`
 --> src/module2/mod.rs:6:14
  |
6 |   use crate::module2::SomeStruct;
  |              ^^^^^^^ maybe a missing crate `module2`?
```

When the contents of the files as as follows.

#### src/module1/mod.rs

```rust
pub mod module1 {

  // -- snip --

  use crate::module2::SomeStruct;

  }

  // -- snip --

}
```

#### src/module2/mod.rs

```rust
pub mod module2 {

  // --snip--

  pub struct SomeStruct;

  }

  // -- snip--

}
```

#### src/main.rs

```rust
mod module1;

fn main() {
  // -- snip--
}
```

Why is this and how can it be fixed? All relevant modules and structs are public. A [relevant chapter in the Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch07-05-separating-modules-into-different-files.html).

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What is `token`? Is that something defined or imported in `module2`?

Comment: @SCappella I changed the names of things as they are irrelevant. That `token` was a leftover from the change. Itäs fixed now.

Comment: I'm not getting an error with the code you posted. There must be something else that's wrong.

Comment: @SCappella My guess is the directory layout, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong there. The modules are in different files, at the same module level.

Comment: I'm actually a little confused now. What file is `pub mod module1 {//snip}...` in? I thought it was in `main.rs`, but then you wouldn't need any external files. The error message suggests that `use crate::module2::SomeStruct;` is in `src/module2/mod.rs`. You should try to piece together a minimal, reproducible example. Actually set up the file structure and everything. When you post the code, make sure it's clear which file it appears in.

Comment: @SCappella The project structure is right at the beginning of the original post, The modules are placed in folders of the same name in files `mod.rs`, as that is how `rustc` instructed me to do previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration of a module (e.g. `pub mod module1`) happens outside of that module. There are [two kinds](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/modules.html) of module declarations: one where the definition is right after (inside braces), and one where the definition is in another file.

For modules in a separate file, you'll simply say `pub mod module1;` *in that module's parent.* For your structure, you'll want to have `pub mod module1;` and `pub mod module2` in `main.rs`.

Inside the module file (e.g. `src/module1/mod.rs`), you don't need `pub mod module1` at all. You can just have its items directly in the file.

So your setup should be

## `src/main.rs`

```
pub mod module1;
pub mod module2;
```

## `src/module1/mod.rs`

```
// -- snip --

use crate::module2::SomeStruct;

// -- snip
```

## `src/module2/mod.rs`

```
// --snip--

pub struct SomeStruct;

// -- snip--
```